# Fixing ArgumentException in UWP enum DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, enums, uwp, dependency-properties, argumentexception

I have the following code in a UWP app:

```
public sealed partial class CanvasMapControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveInteractionModeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ActiveInteractionMode),
                                    typeof(InteractionMode),
                                    typeof(CanvasMapControl),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(InteractionMode.None, CanvasMapControl_InteractionModeChanged));

    public InteractionMode ActiveInteractionMode {
        get => (InteractionMode)GetValue(ActiveInteractionModeProperty);
        set => SetValue(ActiveInteractionModeProperty, value);
    }

    private static void CanvasMapControl_InteractionModeChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ((CanvasMapControl)obj).InteractionModeInternal = (InteractionMode)args.NewValue;
    }

    // ...rest of class...
}
```

InteractionMode is an enum. When I attempt to run my app, I get the following exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'MyApp.CanvasMapControl' threw an exception.'
>
> Inner Exception
>
> ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. createDefaultValueCallback

Things I've tried:

- Changing the DependencyProperty to an int and casting
- Passing null in for the PropertyMetadata
- Passing null in for the default value of the PropertyMetadata
- Passing a function instead of a value for the default value

No matter what I try, on startup it always throws the above exception targeting the SetValue line of ActiveInteractionMode. What am I missing that is making this not work?

---

**Update**: InteractionModeInternal is a simple private property that will be used to allow me to temporarily change the ActiveInteractionMode during processing

```
private InteractionMode _interactionModeInternal;

private InteractionMode InteractionModeInternal
{
    get => _interactionModeInternal;
    set
    {
        _interactionModeInternal = value;
        OnInteractionModeInternalChanged(value);
    }
}

private void OnInteractionModeInternalChanged(InteractionMode interactionMode)
{
    Log.Debug($"InternalInteractionMode changed to {interactionMode}");
}
```

I currently have no logic driven off of it, except that it logs a string to the console.

---

**Update 2**: After further debugging, I have found the reason the crash happens on startup is that I was binding values to these properties in XAML. After commenting out those bindings, the application was able to startup, but then attempting to access either the Get or Set for ActiveInteractionMode would cause this same error with createDefaultValueCallback to occur.

Comment: What happens if you change the line `new PropertyMetadata(InteractionMode.None, ...));` to this: `new PropertyMetadata(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, ...));`

Comment: @Laith No effect. Same issue.

Comment: Can you try closing visual studio and in the solution directory of your code, delete all `bin` and `obj` directories. I have a feeling something is locked and your auto-generated code-behind is not updating.

Comment: @Laith Closed VS, deleted the bin and obj folders for all the projects in the solution. When I opened it back up it had a hard time finding a lot of Framework classes, but after doing a package restore (which said everything was already downloaded) it found them all. When running the app though, same problem.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about the property `InteractionModeInternal` ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have updated the question with additional information about InteractionModeInternal

Comment: Are you by any chance accessing that property from a thread other than main UI thread? Because according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.PropertyMetadata) the `CreateDefaultValueCallback` is used in such events, which in turn requires to use static `PropertyMetadata.Create` method rather than a public constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this in the future, I'm posting this as the answer as it identifies the specific problem I was having. I don't know if I was doing something wrong, or if this was a bug either in UWP or on my phone, but I no longer have this code so cannot debug further.

> **Update 2:** After further debugging, I have found the reason the crash
>   happens on startup is that I was binding values to these properties in
>   XAML. After commenting out those bindings, the application was able to
>   startup, but then attempting to access either the Get or Set for
>   ActiveInteractionMode would cause this same error with
>   createDefaultValueCallback to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a sample by you providing segment code. I tried to reproduce your issue. But the issue did not occur in my project. And I have uploaded the [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/ArgumentExceptionTest.git) to github. Please check. The following code is custom control, You could compare the following code to find out if there is a problem in your project.

```
 public enum InteractionMode
 {
  None,
  Initiative,
  Passive
 }

 public sealed partial class CustomUserControl : UserControl
 {
     public CustomUserControl()
     {
         this.InitializeComponent();
     }

 public InteractionMode ActiveInteractionMode
 {
     get { return (InteractionMode)GetValue(ActiveInteractionModeProperty); }
     set { SetValue(ActiveInteractionModeProperty, value); }
 }

 public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveInteractionModeProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("ActiveInteractionMode", typeof(InteractionMode), typeof(CustomUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(InteractionMode.None, CanvasMapControl_InteractionModeChanged));

 private static void CanvasMapControl_InteractionModeChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
 {
     if (args.OldValue != args.NewValue)
     {
         ((CustomUserControl)obj).InteractionModeInternal = (InteractionMode)args.NewValue;
     }
 }

 private InteractionMode _interactionModeInternal;

 private InteractionMode InteractionModeInternal
 {
     get
     {
         return _interactionModeInternal;
     }

     set
     {
         _interactionModeInternal = value;
         OnInteractionModeInternalChanged(value);
     }
 }

 private void OnInteractionModeInternalChanged(InteractionMode interactionMode)
 {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"InternalInteractionMode changed to {interactionMode}");
 }
```